# .htaccess file does'nt work properly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have create the .htaccess in following way

```
 RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /school1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I mean that when user hit the `'school1/schools/schools'` they will get the contents of 'school1/index.php?path=schools/schools'  It is working properly but css js and images requests are going to the `school1/schools/[js|css|img]/...` as per directory instead of `school1/[js|css|img]`

I m not getting why they are getting the schools part from the url.
if i m fire `http://demo.cwdesigns.org/school1/dashboard` it renders properly but when i `fire  http://demo.cwdesigns.org/school1/schools/schools`

Please help me I have wasted my long time for this problem. If you want any extra info please comment it.

**update 1**
 as per the first answer I have added the base tag to my head section

```
<head>
        <base href="http://demo.cwdesings.org/school1" />

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Student Portal | Dashboard</title>
```

but it doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have extra `/`'s in your URL's path, the browser is incorrectly guessing the relative URL base for all of your relative links. If the browser thinks it's loading:

```
/school1/schools/schools
```

Then the relative base will be: `/school1/schools/` and all relative links will have that prepended to them. "Relative" links are relative to where the page is being loaded, and the browser doesn't know anything about your rewrites.

To fix it, either make your links absolute (starts with `http://your-domain.com/school1/` or `/school1/`), or add a relative base to the headers of your pages:

```
<base href="/school1/" />
```

Comment: where should be base tag added at head section or anywhere in the website

Comment: @siddhesh inside the `<head> </head>` tags

Comment: I have updated the question with my header.php file added base tag but doesn't work.

Comment: Oh i solved problem with the trailing slash that was missed by me in typo